# recapcha v2. На странице 2 рекапчи, как получить g-recaptcha-response второй

Tags: php, javascript, валидация, recaptcha

На странице 2 рекапчи сделаны таким образом

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" data-size="compact" async defer></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="a1" data-sitekey="sitekey" class="g-recaptcha"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" data-size="compact" async defer></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="a2" data-sitekey="sitekey" class="g-recaptcha"></div>
```

Валидация делается на стороне сервера, ajax'ом отправляю значения

```
$("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
```

С первой формы все приходит правильно. Со второй возвращает значение - `undefinded`.

Со второй отправлял значение селектором

```
$("#a2 #g-recaptcha-response").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у кого-то возникнит похожая проблема. Дело в том что нет такого элемента как

```
$("#a2 #g-recaptcha-response")
```

если мы генерируем 2 капчи на стр то врорая будет доступна по селектору

`#g-recaptcha-response-1"` или `.g-recaptcha-response`.

Значение можно взять каскадным селектором

```
$("#a2 .g-recaptcha-response").val();
```